# how to make 16bit to 8bit like that 0x0300 to 0x03 and 0x00 by python?

Tags: python

how to make 16bit to 8bit like that 0x0300 to 0x03 and 0x00 by python?

i try to it like that

```
reg = 0x0300
print(reg[0:4], reg[4::])..
```

it show me that 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
reg = 0x0316
regbinary = bin(reg)
print(regbinary)
regBotoom = regbinary[-8::]
print(regBotoom)
result = hex('0b'+regBotoom)
print(result)
```

it show me that

```
0b1100010110

00010110
```

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get lower and higher 8 bits with bitwise AND and shifting:

```
reg = 0x0316
lowBits = reg & 0xFF
highBits = (reg >> 8) & 0xFF
print(lowBits)
print(highBits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise Operators:

```
x = 0x4321
y = x >> 8 
  = 0x43
z = x & 0x00ff
  = 0x21
```

You can not manipulate an int like you are trying to do without converting it to a string first.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're after the answer @jafarlihi gave, where `reg` is really just an `int` and you shift its value to get the values you're after.

However, you may also want to see this:

```
import struct

reg = 790

regb = struct.pack('h', reg)
print(regb)

msb, lsb = struct.unpack('bb', regb)
print(msb, lsb)

regb_2 = struct.pack('bb', msb, lsb)
print(regb, regb_2)

value = struct.unpack('h', regb)
print(reg, value)
```

Result:

```
b'\x16\x03'
22 3
b'\x16\x03' b'\x16\x03'
790 (790,)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reg = 0x0300
print(hex((reg >> 8) & 0xFF))
print(hex(reg & 0xFF))
```

Output :

```
0x3
0x0
```